# autoload ggplot2 custom theme

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes

I'm using R and Jupyter and would like a custom theme to be loaded automatically upon startup. I've defined a custom theme function, and when I define it within a session it works as expected. I've tried putting the definition in my local .Rprofile, but when I restart an R kernel the theme is no longer available. How do I make these themes persist across sessions?

For example, the theme_nothing is defined via

```
theme_nothing <- function(base_size = 12, base_family = "Helvetica")
{
theme_bw(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) %+replace%
  theme(
        rect             = element_blank(),
        line             = element_blank(),
        text             = element_blank()
       )
}e
```

in a cell, and when that cell is executed I can use this theme. But if I close the session, I need to redefine the theme in order to use it. I want it to load automatically with any new R kernel.

(I've read [the theme vignette](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/vignettes/themes.html) but didn't find anything on persistance.)

Answer (score 1):

Insert theme_set at the start of your script

```
theme_set(theme_nothing())
```

To do this you will also have to include a path to the location the theme is stored first eg,

```
source('~where/the/file/is.R)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I added the theme_set(theme_nothing()) command after the function definition in the .Rprofile, closed down the notebook session and restarted, but still no dice. I again get the error "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): could not find function "theme_nothing"" when calling it from ggplot.

Comment: `theme_set` works from inside your r script, and only if you provide a `source` path to file containing your custom theme before it in the script. If you're trying to change the default behaviour of ggplot2 when it loads then... (jedi hand wave)... this is not the answer you are looking for